# python pdf2image from link "Unable to get page count"

Tags: python, pdf, python-requests

I have a PDF link I want to convert to an Image so I ran this

```
import requests
import pdf2image
x = "https://www.criticallink.com/wp-content/uploads/ISO-9001-2015-Certificate.pdf"
pdf = requests.get(x,stream=True,timeout=30)
images = pdf2image.convert_from_bytes(pdf.raw.read())
```

but I get this error

```
PDFPageCountError: Unable to get page count.
Syntax Warning: May not be a PDF file (continuing anyway)
Syntax Error (19): Illegal character '>'
Syntax Error (46): Illegal character ')'
Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table
```

what should I do?

UPDATE:

```
pdf.raw.read()[:100]
b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x9c\xfdy@Rk\xfc>\x8a\xbe\x80\x8a\x9aC\x03\x15\x9aSY\n\xb5SI\xcaY\xd1\xb6\x13N\x80\xed\xdc\x91\x99i)X\x9a8U\x98\x8a\xd9\xb4\xd9\x84\x9a\x94F\x0e\x14\xa0\xb5\xcb\xac\x1d\xa6V\xa6\rH\xb5\xb7\xa2hZ6\x99\x9aJdj\xe2\x909\xdc\xe5\xfe}\xcf\xf9\xdd{\xcf\xf9\xe3\x9e\xbb\xfa#'
```

Comment: print out the first few 100 bytes from `pdf.raw.read()` so that you/we can see what it is you're getting back.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel `pdf.raw.read()` outputs `b''`

Comment: That's because you've already read all the contents. Do the print before the call to convert_from_bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're getting a GZIP-encoded response. Try the following.

```py
import gzip
import requests
import pdf2image

url = "https://www.criticallink.com/wp-content/uploads/ISO-9001-2015-Certificate.pdf"
response = requests.get(url, stream=True, timeout=30)
pdf = gzip.open(response.raw)
images = pdf2image.convert_from_bytes(pdf.read())
```

Alternatively, you can use

```py
import requests
import pdf2image

url = "https://www.criticallink.com/wp-content/uploads/ISO-9001-2015-Certificate.pdf"
response = requests.get(url, timeout=30)
images = pdf2image.convert_from_bytes(response.content)
```

and let `requests` do the decoding for you.